# Finding the cost of Hessian-vector product computation?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Suppose we have a composition of functions $F(x)=f_n \circ f_{n-1} \circ \ldots \circ f_1 \circ x$, where $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{d_{i-1}}\to \mathbb{R}^{d_i}$

The Jacobian of $F$, has shape $d_n \times d_0$ and can be written as a product of Jacobians of $f_i$'s. We can assume these Jacobians are provided, then the minimum cost to compute Jacobian is obtained by solving the [matrix chain problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication). What about the minimum cost to compute the Hessian-vector product?

More precisely, define Hessian-vector product of $F$

$$\text{hvp}(F,x,v)_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^{d_0} \frac{\partial^2 F_i(x)}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} v_k $$

Where $\frac{\partial^2 F_i(x)}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}$ is the Hessian of $F$, a tensor with shape $d_n\times d_0 \times d_0$ and $v$ is a vector with $d_0$ elements.

Given the list of dimensions $d_0,\ldots,d_n$, what is the minimum cost to compute $\text{hvp}$?

PS, for $n=3$, hvp computation is visualized below as a sum of 3 tensor network [diagrams](https://tensornetwork.org/diagrams/):
[image]